# Brownie package manager: pm or ethpm

Tags: brownie

I have read several documentations about brownie.

I have find 2 ways to install a package like openzeppelin-contracts:

```
$ brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0
```

and

```
$ brownie ethpm install <package>
```

I do not understand the difference between this 2 commands. What's the difference between pm and ethpm ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first - `pm` - uses [Brownie's own package manager](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html#brownie-package-manager).

The second - `ethpm` - uses the [Ethereum Package Manager](https://www.ethpm.com/), which is *"a decentralized package manager used to distribute EVM smart contracts and projects"*.

Both are supported by Brownie, as detailed in the [docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html#brownie-package-manager).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that pm is centralized whereas ethpm is decentralized ? How can this be possible to have a decentralized package manager ? Is there a risk to get corrupted packages ?

Comment: Git is a distributed version control system. Github is the centralized service provided on top of git. Not sure if the analogy perfectly holds here, but it might.